# Spring data - MongoDB - $regex search

Tags: regex, mongodb, spring-data

I use Spring data with MongoDB in my application, one of my repository classes look like this:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {

@Query("{$or : [{'name': { $regex: ?0, $options:'i' }}, {'description': { $regex: ?0, $options:'i' }}]}")
List<Product> findProductByRegexString(final String regexString);

...
}
```

This method I invoke like this:

```
public class ProductServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest {

@Test
public void shouldSearchProductBySubString() throws BusinessException {

    final Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
    tenant.setName("TestTenant");
    final Tenant createdTenant = tenantService.create(tenant);
    Assert.assertNotNull(createdTenant);

    final Product product1 = new Product();
    product1.setName("Wander");
    product1.setDescription("Das ist das Test Produkt 1");
    product1.setTenant(createdTenant);
    final Product createdProduct1 = productService.create(product1);
    Assert.assertNotNull(createdProduct1);

    final Product product2 = new Product();
    product2.setName("Wunder baum");
    product2.setDescription("Ein different Produkt 2");
    product2.setTenant(createdTenant);
    final Product createdProduct2 = productService.create(product2);
    Assert.assertNotNull(createdProduct2);

    final List<Product> allProducts = productService.findAllProductsByTenant(createdTenant);
    Assert.assertEquals(2, allProducts.size());

    final List<Product> products = productService.findProductsByRegex("/^Wand/");
    Assert.assertEquals(1, products.size());
    }
}
```

and it works fine. 
If I try to use this chars:

[image: regex]

e.g:

```
final List<Product> products = productService.findProductsByRegex("/^Wand/");
```

I do not get any result with string **/^Wand/**
Does anyone have any explanation why it does not work with **/^Wand/**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also need to quote:

```
public static String escapeForRegex(String input) {
    return input.replace("\\", "\\\\")
                .replace(".", "\\.")
                .replace("*", "\\*")
                .replace("+", "\\+")
                .replace("?", "\\?")
                .replace("{", "\\{")
                .replace("}", "\\}")
                .replace("(", "\\(")
                .replace(")", "\\)")
                .replace("[", "\\[")
                .replace("]", "\\]")
                .replace("^", "\\^")
                .replace("$", "\\$")
                .replace("|", "\\|");
}
```

Comment: Pattern.quote(input) does this in a better way

Answer (score 8):

`/expression/` is alternative syntax used in shell & js drivers.

For java drivers you just need to use `"^Wand"`

Try

```
final List<Product> products = productService.findProductsByRegex("^Wand");
```

More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)